# in dlib python API document, what does "->None" mean?

Tags: python, dlib

In dlib Python API document I see these contents(ignore the colors, I don't know why..),
(from http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.rectangles)

```
class dlib.chip_details
WHAT THIS OBJECT REPRESENTS This object describes where an image chip is to be extracted from within another image. In particular, it specifies that the image chip is contained within the rectangle self.rect and that prior to extraction the image should be rotated counter-clockwise by self.angle radians. Finally, the extracted chip should have self.rows rows and self.cols columns in it regardless of the shape of self.rect. This means that the extracted chip will be stretched to fit via bilinear interpolation when necessary.

__init__(*args, **kwargs)
Overloaded function.

__init__(self: dlib.chip_details, rect: dlib.drectangle) -> None
__init__(self: dlib.chip_details, rect: dlib.rectangle) -> None
ensures
self.rect == rect_
self.angle == 0
self.rows == rect.height()
self.cols == rect.width()
__init__(self: dlib.chip_details, rect: dlib.drectangle, size: int) -> None
__init__(self: dlib.chip_details, rect: dlib.rectangle, size: int) -> None
ensures
...
```

What does "->None" mean?

Comment: It's a type annotation. In this case it means that the `__init__` method return  `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-> None` is part of python [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). In this case it means that the function returns nothing.

> Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Comment: I saw '-> NoneType'  expression (https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html). Is this another expression used in type specification?

Comment: @ChanKim Yes it is